# Change Table of Contents in Appendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

Is there a way to change the layout of the section part of the Table of Contents once you hit the appendices?

I want the following to have Appendix A. Title, and then not the page number:
[image]

The Appendix A from my \thesection is covering up the title.  I've tried "renewing" l@section to try and adjust, but I don't really know how.

I'm setting up my appendix command like:

```
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}    
  {\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}

\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \clearemptydoublepage
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}

  \renewcommand\section{%
      \renewcommand\thesection{\appendixname \ \@Alph\c@section}
                               \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\centering\normalfont
                               \normalsize\bfseries\scshape}}

  \renewcommand\subsection{%
     \renewcommand\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}
                                 \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\scshape}}

  \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
}
```

And then doing:

```
\appendix

\makeappendixtitle{Add title for appendix A}
\section{Title}
\subsection{Appendix Sub}
First appendix
```

My appendix itself looks fine like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please don't post such fragments only. Post the compilable version of your document that generates the issue. Looking into that debris of code above I don't feel very comfortable. Where did you get this code? Have you looked into `tocloft` -- it provides nice means to change the look of a `ToC` etc. (easier than changing `\l@section` etc!)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler to use the `appendix` page.  This has an option to put the word `Appendix` before each appendix in the body, but suppress it in the table of contents.

[image: Sample contents]

[image: Sample appendix]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Ordinary section}

\cleardoublepage
\begin{appendices}
  \section{Title}
  \subsection{Appendix Sub}
  First appendix
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```